# Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative68ReleaseKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

Getting this error `Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative68ReleaseKotlin'.`  when I am trying to build my android app with this command `android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease` I have tried classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0")` changed it to my version no idea what to do next?

Comment: can it be related to this issue here : https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/7466

Comment: Was not related, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

just update your RNNKotlinVersion = "1.6.0" in android/build.gradle it solve for me. https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/7565#issuecomment-1200447182

Comment: Hi ! i have tried this but still i'm getting the same error

Comment: Make sure to update `android/build.gradle` file as well with new version number. For example:

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is that the problem was not gradle but at the end I have a problem that a function in java for react native navigation was using Bundle but I never imported it:

```
error: cannot find symbol
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class MainActivity
1 error
```

So I imported the Bundle that since the tutorial I am following the teacher doesn't need that import I believe that windows users has to. This is the import in the MainActivity.java: yourApp\android\app\src\main\java\com\god1sthwapp\MainActivity.java

And this is the import:
import android.os.Bundle;